# Streaming Google Drive and mp4upload in video.js

Tags: google-drive-api, html5-video, video.js

Greeting's Everyone i have a big problem!
We reworked our new anime site, and we want to use Video.js as a prime video streaming tool. Because, player has captions(cc) option. Well i cant figure out how i can add Google Drive video to it, i tried many different solutions and none of them fixed the prob. Everyone know for the classic embed for video.js. You can found it on the video.js site, but when i google drive link to src. nothing happens.
These are some links i tried to add to to video.js
https://891370689a6d9fcfd87eec0ed9fdf670043854d6.googledrive.com/host/0B-ZzXoxSIb5HSnVCd3lmaUhoV1E

The 2nd one is pretty big:
https://r16---sn-c0q7lnee.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=d730678f257a3f84&itag=22&source=webdrive&app=docs&ip=109.93.221.142&ipbits=0&expire=1438612027&sparams=requiressl%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Cexpire&signature=1F77F97FBEF2B00A1FF56026B83880C7CC013F5.4EC6427F2BB46C796DC5AE1559BF291D5A10C60A&key=ck2&mm=30&mn=sn-c0q7lnee&ms=nxu&mt=1438608303&mv=m&pl=19&cpn=BbEbbwDSDUjYylmz

None of this worked i even tried a lot of things :(.
The only true and real way to embed Google Drive is this:

```
<embed allowfullscreen="true" width="848px" height="480px" name="plugin" src="https://video.google.com/get_player?ps=docs&amp;partnerid=30&amp;theme=light&amp;hl=sr&amp;showinfo=0&amp;cc_load_policy=1&amp;docid=0BxuJWWG104pKRHJsVDZoa0ViYk0;BASE_URL=https://docs.google.com/" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
</embed>
```

I don't have problem to use this but a lot of animes which are old cant be found online and are pretty low to encode, so i need the way to upload it on google drive and embed it with Video.js and put CC.

I appreciate all the help and thanks in advance! If there is no way, then i don't know what to do.
Greeting's Boo

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
<source src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=VIDEO_ID" type='video/mp4' res="480" label='480'/>
```